# Cypress POST request, how to access 'fields' section of reponse body

Tags: javascript, post, response, cypress

I want to send a POST request in Cypress that triggers the validation to reject the request

According to Postman, the body of the response looke like this:

```json
    "code": "validation_error",
    "message": "Validation error, please see fields property for details",
    "fields": 
    {
        "TariffData[rate_gp]": " Invalid rate_gp. Expected: 9.35. Imported: 19.35"
    }
```

I am interested in the "fields" section, so I tried to assert with this code:

```js
const api_key = require('../../fixtures/contracts/api_test_client1.json')
const body1 = require('../../fixtures/contracts/body_test_client1.json')
describe('test POST/client validation', () => {

  it('send POST/client request', function () {
        cy.request({
              method: 'POST',
              url: Cypress.env('staging_url') + '/service/clients',
              headers: {
                       'API-KEY': api_key,
                       },
              body:    body1,
              failOnStatusCode:false
                  })
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(400)
                expect(response.body.fields).to.contain('"TariffData[rate_gp]": " Invalid rate_gp. Expected: 9.35. Imported: 19.35"')
                    })
  )}
)}
```

Yet this leads to an error:

> AssertionError
>
> object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given

Yes, the error message ends there. Any ideas how I can make an assertion that the response contains this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to present the expected value as an object, not as a string

```js
  expect(response.body.fields)
    .to.contain({
      "TariffData[rate_gp]": " Invalid rate_gp. Expected: 9.35. Imported: 19.35"
    })
```

If you looks at the docs [chaijs API](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) they show, for example

```js
expect({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}).to.include({a: 1, b: 2});
```

and `contain` is a synonym for `include`

You could also try `to.deep.equal`, as it seems you are specifying the total `fields` property

```js
  expect(response.body.fields)
    .to.deep.eq({
      "TariffData[rate_gp]": " Invalid rate_gp. Expected: 9.35. Imported: 19.35"
    })
```

Comment: 100% correct. That was my whole mistake! Tried with both include and contain and they work like a charm! Thanks so much

Comment: And just for compIeteness sake I also tried deep.eq, yet this did not work in my case as ```({
      "TariffData[rate_gp]": " Invalid rate_gp. Expected: 9.35. Imported: 19.35"
    })```actually triggers 2 assertions. One for the first string and one for the 2nd (after the colon). So it first compares whether the fields section matches "TariffData[rate_gp]" which fails as it's only a part of the response. Just wanted to add that in case someone else comes across this very helpful answer :)

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, something to keep in mind.